# Useful real-world APIs to test against

Tags: automated-testing, c#, rest-api

In order for me to firm up my understanding of API testing I'm looking at testing against some real-world API's. For understanding, I'm going to be writing my API tests in C#, ideally utilising RestSharp

I was just after some advise from people as to some API's which would be good to test against for training purposes, as hopefully some of these have been utilised in the past by people. I'm looking to cover off different types of authentication, parameters and headers being passed across, sending different types of requests(GET, PUT, POST etc) and in turn analysing responses(be it in XML or JSON format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub is really useful for lists of resources and I came across one yesterday that is a collection of [free APIs for use in web development](https://github.com/toddmotto/public-apis). <- I think you'd be good to test most any of these APIs for practice as well. The List is fairly descriptive mentioning which APIs have auth or not and then you can click to the API's, read the documentation and figure out what requests they accept.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API playground for learning purpose.

https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use public registries of REST APIs like [ProgrammableWeb](https://www.programmableweb.com/). Many APIs listed there are either free, or free for certain traffic load per month, or they provide test accounts.

Answer (score 0):

How about google?  That'd be straightforward enough, they document it abundantly, and you'd know what to expect back..

Answer (score 0):

> **Try https://getsandbox.com/ to stub real word APIs**

I'd suggest once you get more versed with the basics of APIs you set up your own stub API using https://getsandbox.com/.

You can create any type of verb, and with a little bit of JavaScript you can even drive out some scenarios too.